# Use CSS to give a absolute element 100% browser height

Tags: css

I have a overlay using a position absolute element. The overlay element can have more content then what is in the viewport so position fixed is not doing the trick. At the moment the background color of the overlay is only the size of the viewport, and not the browser. And this messes up the content.

Check the plunker for an example, http://plnkr.co/edit/r37LE4BhvW7UkNWPfsJN?p=preview

```
html, body{
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.absolute{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't removing `height: 100%` resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
html, body{
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.absolute{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

to

```
 html, body{
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.absolute{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  **height:auto;**
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The line important is height:auto;

Comment: I'll upvote you for the `height auto` but in the end my problem was mainly developing in Ubuntu and a older version of Chrome!